# mapStateToProps not working when route path contains multiple path variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a react project connected to redux. My problem is that when I have a Route path defined in my App.js with any url parameter more than just a single slash and variable (ex: '/foo/bar' OR '/foo/:id') my component fails to fetch data from my backend and I am receiving 404 not found. I suspect it has something to do with mapStateToProps but am not sure. I am fetching the data correctly when the path is '/foo' and am able to console log the values of the the data that is mapped to props but if I change that path to '/foo/bar' in App.js Route path the prop is returning 404. I am not sure how to go about fixing this.

App.js

```
render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                <HeaderNav />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

                    // path won't mapStateToProps properly
                    <Route path="/collection/:type"
                        render={(props) => <Collection {...props} />} 
                    />
                <Footer />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    };
```

Collection.js

```
class Collection extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCollection("Tents");
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.collection) // returns 404

        let collection;

        if(this.props.collection.Tents) {
            collection = this.props.collection.Tents.map(product => {
                return (
                    <div key={product.item_number} className="container-product">
                        <img src={product.image_url} alt="product"/>
                        <h1>{product.title}</h1>
                        <h2>${product.price}</h2>
                        <p>{product.rating}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            });
        }


        return (
            <div>
                <div id="container-all-products">

                        {collection}

                </div>

            </div>
        );
    };

};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    collection: state.products.collections
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCollection })(Collection);
```

Comment: looks like an issue with your router setup

Comment: @YasserZubair how so? any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: All of my router code is done so in App.js which is shared. Not sure what you mean besides that .. @YasserZubair

Comment: try changing 
`<Route path="/collection/:type"
                        render={(props) => <Collection {...props} />} 
                    />`

To 
`<Route exact={true} path="/collection/:type"
                        render={(props) => <Collection {...props} />} 
                    />`

Try this and follow up.

Comment: in short add exact={true} as a prop to your route.

Comment: @YasserZubair same result :/